# Upper bound for most likely category in multinomial random vector NOT being max count realized

Tags: probability-distributions, multinomial-coefficients, distribution-tails

Let $(X_1,\dotsc, X_k)$ be distributed multinomial with parameters $n, (p_1\dotsc,p_k)$ and suppose $p_1>p_j$ for $j\neq 1$ so that category 1 is the most likely outcome from any given realization.  I am looking for an upper bound on the probability that $X_1$ will not be the maximum realized category i.e. $P(\max_j X_j\neq X_1)$.  Does anyone know of a good reference for such a problem?

One approach I had is to look at $P(X_1-X_j\leq 0)$ for any $j$, which can be bounded using Hoeffding's inequality:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality

I can upper bound this uniformly for all $j$ i.e. a single bound derived using Hoeffding works.  I can then bound $P(\cup_{j\neq 1} X_1-X_j\leq 0)$ using the sum by applying the uniform bound to each term in the sum.  My issue is: I think the upper bound is too conservative, particularly if $k$ is large.  I don't really have a theoretical reason to think so, just a hunch.

Any comments on how I might better approach this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm also working on a similar problem - have you made any progress? Also, how do you use Hoeffding's inequality to bound the difference of $X_1$ and $X_j$? The standard version only applies to sums of random variables.